# Position or Float - One div under the other (Top div contains a fixed nav)

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

My HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="inner">
            <h1>Meat City</h1>

        <nav>   

    <a href="#">Bacon</a>
    <a href="#">Steak</a>
    <a href="#">Crabs</a>
    <a href="#">Burgers</a>

        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
        <h4>Paragraph 1</h4>

    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet meatloaf sirloin chuck, strip steak fatback beef ribs doner salami. </p>
</div>
<div>
        <h4>Paragraph 2</h4>

    <p>Shankle beef ribs bacon pancetta, kielbasa landjaeger andouille boudin.  </p>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f6f6f6;

    height: 150px;

    border:1px;
    border-color:green;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/awozkq5p/3/

Having some difficulty figuring out how to use float and / or position to stack one div over the other.

Right now my div that contains the fixed nav overlaps my first paragraph.  I don't want the nav to cover up the first paragraph.  I want the first paragraph to start after the fixed nav.

I've been reading about making all the divs float:left, but that doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Why are you using fixed positioning?

Comment: I want to make the nav sticky

Comment: The sticky nav bar would have to be achieved using jquery

Comment: When you use position: fixed you're removing it from the flow. To compensate for that you'd need to apply some `margin-top` to either your first div that's being pulled under, or `padding-top` to a containing `div` that equals the height of your `<header>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:fixed` and `position:absolute` will always overlap your content.

You can add `margin-top` property to get this work. Example:

```
div.header + div {
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

Comment: +1 and just a note: This is OK only if the header height is always specified as 150. (means it will not work with responsive content inside the header)

Comment: There is no relevant solution in this case. If `header` height will change you must change `margin-top` property also.

Comment: exactly (though there's some *tricky* solutions even for that case)

Comment: Could always shift both values via `media queries` if you're looking to avoid js.

Comment: I added a class on my first div containing the paragraph.  Then set margin-top:150px; It worked and was the quickest way to fix my issue.  A lot of other great suggestions that I'll have to look into.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To layer divs over each other, you can use the **z-index** property in conjunction with the **position** or **display** properties.

Layered divs:

```
|---------|
|         |
|  |----------|
|  |          |
|--|          |
   |          |
   |----------|
```

To stack your divs vertically on the page, one below the other, just remove the **position:fixed** property. By default, divs will fill up the available space within the parent container and stack vertically. Once you start fiddling with widths, position, float, z-index and other positioning properties, you'll alter this behavior.

Stacked divs:

```
|---------|
|         |
|         |
|         |
|---------|
|---------|
|         |
|         |
|         |
|---------|
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution but I would still look into some jquery plugins where the navbar would also resize when scrolling

http://jsfiddle.net/awozkq5p/5/

added a

```
.spacer{padding-top: 150px;}
```